# Does Christianity claim itself to be the final revelation from God?

Tags: special-revelation

Does Christianity claim to be the last true religion that will ever exist, or does it admit the possibility of being supplanted by a new revelation, like Judaism was with Christianity?

Comment: This depends on your definition of "final." I think most Christians believe they receive revelations from God all the time.  Whom should I marry? What job should I take? Should I attend university? Answers to all of these questions could be considered "revelations from God"...

Comment: This depends on who you ask. Most Trinitarian Christians would say yes, but LDS of course claim that their scriptures are also inspired.

Answer (score 6):

Christianity<sup>1</sup> doesn't make claims about *itself* but rather makes claims about **Jesus**. And those claims are based on the Bible, which records Jesus' own words. So what does Jesus say about being supplanted by a new revelation? He was asked exactly this question - here is His answer:

> When the men came to Jesus, they said, ‘John the Baptist sent us to you to ask, “Are you the one who is to come, or **should we expect someone else?**”’
>
> At that very time Jesus cured many who had diseases, illnesses and evil spirits, and gave sight to many who were blind.  So he replied to the messengers, ‘**Go back and report to John what you have seen and heard: the blind receive sight, the lame walk, those who have leprosy are cleansed, the deaf hear, the dead are raised, and the good news is proclaimed to the poor.  Blessed is anyone who does not stumble on account of me.**’

[Luke 7:20-23](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%207:20-23&version=NIVUK)

Furthermore, in another place He specifically says that there is no other way to God than through Him:

> Jesus answered, ‘I am the way and the truth and the life. **No one comes to the Father except through me.**

[John 14:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:6&version=NIVUK)

So He's the [First Revelation and The Last](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+22:13&version=NIVUK). As Peter said<sup>2</sup>, *"[There is no one else.](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+6:68&version=NIVUK)"*

<sub>1 And here you'd have to specify which *flavour* of Christianity you're talking about.</sub>

<sub>2 My paraphrase.</sub>

Comment: This is a great answer to push you over 10K.  Welcome to the big leagues!

Answer (score 2):

Jesus' claims about Himself, such as there is no way to God but through Him (John 14:6) expressly reject any newer revelation that will supplant faith in Jesus Christ.

The book of Revelation shows us what will happen for a good while to come, and it shows Jesus, the Lamb of God, on the throne at the end (Rev. 21:22).

According to 1 Cor. 15:20-28 we find that the God of the Bible will endure forever; there will be no other gods from new revelations to replace Him, and Jesus is the agent through which God will draw all people to Himself.

Answer (score 1):

Christianity is based on the New Testament. What ever the New Testament says, that is what Christianity believes.

According to the NT, Jesus is the promised Messiah from the Old Testament, which is the scripture for the Jews. Basically, without the Jewish scripture, there is no New Testament, which means no Christianity. The New Testament claims that Jesus is the promised Messiah whom the Jews were waiting, even today. Which means that Christianity is the completion or the ultimate stage of Judaism.

Christianity itself never claims to be a new religion. Christians believe that God is a Trinity, three persons in one, known as - God the Father, God the Son and God the Holy Spirit. Since Jesus is God the Son, Christianity doesn't produce any new Deity. It's the same God from the Old Testament. Christianity claims that there are many scriptural proves in the Jewish scripture which refers to the Trinity, and also the Messiah as the Son of God who would be flogged and crucified for our sins.

Answer (score 1):

> In the past God spoke to our ancestors through the prophets at many times and in various ways, but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed heir of all things, and through whom also he made the universe. The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact representation of his being, sustaining all things by his powerful word. (Hebrews 1:1-3, NIV)

Hebrews is a long discussion about how Jesus is supreme in every way: compared to angels, to Moses, to the high priests etc. It begins though by noting that Jesus is supreme way God has revealed himself. As Jesus said, "Anyone who has seen me has seen the Father." (John 14:9)

So Jesus is the big definitive revelation from God.

Does that mean that God has not given further revelations after the New Testament? There is no consensus on that question, and the debate between continuationism and cessationism is still ongoing.

Comment: Do you mean to say that continuationism teaches that later revelation can help reduce the ambiguity left in NT (such as regarding afterlife, second coming, baptism, nature of the eucharist, etc)?  Isn't there a consensus that that kind of revelation has been foreclosed after the Montanist heresy?  I thought the cessationism vs. continuationism debate is more to do with spiritual gifts, not about additional revelation.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible (Old and New testaments) presents a progressive revelation of God's plan for man's salvation. Some truths are presented as eternal and unchanging, so every later revelation adds to the former without rejecting those that came before. Conflict surrounds those truths that were specifically intended to be for one dispensation but not a later one, such as animal sacrifice and certain laws intended for Israel but not humanity in general, or not for the time after Jesus' resurrection.

Some important verses:

Moses warns the people to expect another prophet (believed by Christians to be Jesus) in Deuteronomy 18:

> 15 The Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from
>   among you, from your fellow Israelites. You must listen to him.

Jesus taught the continuity of what came before in Matthew 5:

> 17 “Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets;
>   I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. 18 For truly I
>   tell you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter,
>   not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the
>   Law until everything is accomplished.

Jesus prepares his disciples to welcome and obey the Holy Spirit going forward in John 16:

> 12 “I have much more to say to you, more than you can now bear. 13 But
>   when he, the Spirit of truth, comes, he will guide you into all the
>   truth. He will not speak on his own; he will speak only what he hears,
>   and he will tell you what is yet to come. 14 He will glorify me
>   because it is from me that he will receive what he will make known to
>   you. 15 All that belongs to the Father is mine. That is why I said the
>   Spirit will receive from me what he will make known to you.”

The history of the Christian Church since the day of Pentecost has been an attempt to listen to the Holy Spirit and learn from that spirit.

To a certain degree, Scripture supplies a certain sense of finality of the revealed truths of God in Revelation 22:

> 18 I warn everyone who hears the words of the prophecy of this scroll:
>   If anyone adds anything to them, God will add to that person the
>   plagues described in this scroll. 19 And if anyone takes words away
>   from this scroll of prophecy, God will take away from that person any
>   share in the tree of life and in the Holy City, which are described in
>   this scroll.

These words in Revelation stand in contrast against the many promises of future teachings and the arrival of a messiah that were predicted by the earlier prophets, like Isaiah and Jeremiah. They merely echo what Jesus said on the cross in John 19:

> 30 When he had received the drink, Jesus said, “It is finished.” With
>   that, he bowed his head and gave up his spirit.

Ever since Eve was promised in Genesis that her seed would crush the serpent, mankind had been looking forward for its hope. We no longer need to look forward.

It IS finished.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the OP of yes or no will depend to which denomination you belong.

Some denominations believe that information from God will come via a latter day prophet, such as Ellen White or Joseph Smith.  For them, the "final" revelation after the completion of the Old and New Testaments came long after scripture was closed.

Some other denominations believe that information from God comes from other sources besides the bible, such as Catholic with their Tradition and Teaching Magisterium.

For others, information from God is completed some 2,000 years ago as to all things necessary for salvation and life.  They base their beliefs on various scriptures such as the following.

> Beloved, when I gave all diligence to write unto you of the common salvation, it was needful for me to write unto you, and exhort you that ye should earnestly contend for the faith which was once delivered unto the saints. Jude 1:3

> By Silvanus, a faithful brother unto you, as I suppose, I have written briefly, exhorting, and testifying that this is the true grace of God wherein ye stand. 1 Peter 5:12

> Wherefore I will not be negligent to put you always in remembrance of these things, though ye know them, and be established in the present truth. 2 Peter 1:12

> Hold fast the form of sound words, which thou hast heard of me, in faith and love which is in Christ Jesus. 2 Timothy 1:13

> But these are written, that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that believing ye might have life through his name. John 20:31

> These things have I written unto you that believe on the name of the Son of God; that ye may know that ye have eternal life, and that ye may believe on the name of the Son of God.  1 John 5:13

Answer (score 1):

***God did not reveal a religion - he revealed his only-begotten Son. God did not send an organisation - he sent his only-begotten Son.***

To answer your Q it would first have to be made clear what "revelation from God" is, in order to then determine what God's final one was, or whether we can expect something further in the future. ***What it is not*** has to be established. It is not knowledge about God. ***It is what God has chosen to reveal to humanity about himself and his will***, so the various ways God has communicated with humanity need to be explored. I'm not going into that (there are 3 predominant ways). I would just point out that gradually, over the centuries, God has led his people into deeper understanding of his revelation, **culminating in revealing the promised Messiah, Jesus Christ. He is the supreme and final revelation from God** so that those who believe him to be the messiah, the only-begotten Son of God as described in the Bible, have that final revelation.

That is why Christians were warned in the New Testament to "Contend earnestly for the faith that was once for all delivered to the saints" - Jude vs. 3. It has already been delivered (and that was back in the last half of the 1st century A.D.) Further, it also says:

> "God, who in sundry times and in divers manners spake in time past
> unto the fathers by the prophets, hath in these last days spoken unto
> us by his Son, whom he hath appointed heir of all things, by whom also
> he made the worlds; who being the brightness of his glory, and the
> impress of his presence, and upholding all things by the word of his
> power, when he had by himself purged our sins, sat down on the right
> hand of the Majesty on high" (Hebrews 1:1-3 KJV).

Name any prophet, or leader of any denomination, and see whether his qualifications can even begin to approach those above. Of course they cannot! It would be blasphemy even to suggest they could! They might claim to have new "words of knowledge" but this Q is about revelation from God, not what humans claim to know about God showing them things. No human can ever claim to be God's final revelation to us. That privilege belongs only to the eternal, uncreated Son of God, who came to earth as God incarnate, to show us the only way to the Father:

> "Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man
> cometh unto the Father, but by me. If ye had known me, ye should have
> known my Father also... Anyone who has seen me has seen the Father"
> (John 14:6-7 & 9 KJV).

Confirming all this, the very last book of the Bible to be written (circa A.D. 95) stated that is was a revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave to him, and relayed to the apostle John by Christ's angel (Revelation 1:1). And that book of visions and prophecies ends by saying,

> "Blessed is he that keepeth the sayings of the prophecy of this
> book... For I testify unto every man that heareth the words of the
> prophecy of this book, if any man shall add unto these things, God
> shall add unto him the plagues that are written in this book; and if
> any man shall take away from the words of the book of this prophecy,
> God shall take away his part out of the book of life, and out of the
> holy city, and from the things which are written in this book" (Rev.
> 22:7 & 18-19).

Beware any individuals or any religious organisation claiming to have received additional revelations from God. **God's last revealed word is the Word of God, as recorded in the written word of God. Do not look to any religion - look only to the person of Jesus Christ**, resurrected to glory and adored by all heaven's throngs even now, before he spectacularly returns to usher in the Day of Resurrection and Judgment.

Answer (score 0):

When you read Mathew 16:18 and go up a few verses the rock that Jesus is referring to is the statement by Peter “You are the Christ, the Son of the living God.”

Matthew 16:18
18 And I also say to you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build My church, and the gates of Hades shall not prevail against it.

Will it get replaced? - In the above verse the second part is your answer.

John 14:6 
6 Jesus said to him, “I am the way, the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through Me.